# Trying to load html pages onto page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Once an li is clicked I want to load a separate html page with content on the main index page.

HTML

```
 <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="tab-1.html">Planet 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="tab-2.html">Planet 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="tab-3.html">Planet 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="tab-4.html">Planet 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

So once one of the links is clicked I want the jquery to load the content on the same page.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            
 
            // load("location-to-your-file", function(){})
            //var indexCatch =  $('ul li').click(function(){ alert($(this).index()); });  
         
 
                $("li").click(function(){
               
                $("main").load("tab-1.html", function(){
                    
                    // Instead of creating another selector combining it from $(this).hide()
                    // $($(this).hide()).fadeIn(1000);
                    
                    // you can chain the methods:
                    $(this).hide().fadeIn(1000);
                });
            });
```

Comment: so you want the page which name is in the `href` part of the `link` to be loaded after the user click that specific link?

Comment: `$("main")` - do you have a html element called `<main>`?

Comment: Correct! I want the content of tab-1.html to be loaded into the <main> section of the index page.

Answer (score 3):

Its working for me,
save this file **example.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Include</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txt_name">
<a id="link" href="#">Click Test Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("#link").on('click',function(){
value=$("#txt_name").val();
window.location = "tab-1.php?txt_value="+value;
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

save this file **tab-1.php**

```
<b><i>Hello : <?php echo $_GET['txt_value']; ?></i></b>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is probably the fact that you are using `<a>` tags

you don't need them

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li data-href="tab-1.html">Planet 1</li>
        <li data-href="tab-2.html">Planet 2</li>
        <li data-href="tab-3.html">Planet 3</li>
        <li data-href="tab-4.html">Planet 4</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function () {
        $("main").load(this.dataset.href, function(){
            $(this).hide().fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That makes sense about the a tags, but it is still not loading the content into the main section

Comment: In that case there is something wrong with the `html` you haven't shown, or with the content of `tab-#.html` or with the location of `tab-#.html` ... the code above, with a `<main>` tag, works perfectly

Comment: I corrected the error, when clicking on the second link it still brings up the content on tab-1.html not the content on tab-2.html

Comment: the code above works as you require ... how you've implemented it is beyond my control

Answer (score 0):

Here we get the value of that specific link `href` attribute, and inject it into the load function

*NOTE:* As I can't show a demo of it using fiddle or S.O code panel, here is a [**DEMO**](http://test.mi-creativity.com/js-load-pages/) showing how this code works

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("nav a").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var href = $(this).attr("href");
      $("main").load(href).hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="tab-1.html">Planet 1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="tab-2.html">Planet 2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="tab-3.html">Planet 3</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="tab-4.html">Planet 4</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<main></main>
```

Comment: It seems to still not load any of the content of the tab-#.html pages

Comment: this does work, I've tested it before i posted it, are these sub-pages all in the same directory level as this page?

Comment: the problem was because in my example code I used `<div id="container">` and in your code you are using `<main>`, now it is solved and should work for you